# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create dynamic charts based on group by `jSon` as follows:

```js
var data = [{
    "France": {
        "val1": [10, 20, 30, 40]
    },
    "Croatia": {
        "val2": [50, 60, 70, 80]}
}];

for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
console.log(data[i].France);
console.log(data[i].Croatia);

var val = i + 1;
var containerName = 'container' + val;

console.log(containerName);

Highcharts.chart(containerName, {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'France',
        data: data[i].France

    }, {
        name: 'Croatia',
        data: data[i].Croatia

    }]
});
}
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container1">

</div><br/>

<div id="container2">

</div><br />

<div id="container3">

</div>
```

I can show the dataset in the console but in the chart, the series throws an exception as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'France' of undefined
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Should be `i < data.length`, not `i <= data.length`.

Comment: But unfortunately it doesn't generate the charts @Pointy.

Comment: @user8512043 Try with `data[i].France.val1`

Comment: Can you check this - https://jsfiddle.net/fdLbq0rp @Carsten Løvbo Andersen? Am trying to generate charts based on `jSOn` data.

Comment: data is expecting an array of data, you are giving it an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
series: [{
  name: 'France',
  data: d[0].France.val1
}, {
  name: 'Croatia',
  data: d[0].Croatia.val2
}]
```

When you do `data: d[0].France` you say that data is equal `"val1": [10, 20, 30, 40]` 
When you do `data: d[0].France.val1` then you say that data is equal `[10, 20, 30, 40]`

**Demo**

```js
var d = [{
  "France": {
    "val1": [10, 20, 30, 40]
  },
  "Croatia": {
    "val2": [50, 60, 70, 80]
  }
}];

for (var i = 0; i <= d.length; i++) {
  var val = i + 1;
  var containerName = 'container' + val;

  Highcharts.chart(containerName, {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
      ],
      crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
      footerFormat: '</table>',
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'France',
      data: d[0].France.val1
    }, {
      name: 'Croatia',
      data: d[0].Croatia.val2
    }]
  });
}
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container1">

</div><br/>

<div id="container2">

</div><br />

<div id="container3">

</div>
```

Comment: This worked @Carsten Løvbo Andersen. But is it possible to create two different charts based on the dataset? Here's a snippet that I am trying - https://jsfiddle.net/y4su7f8w. One for **France** and another **Croatia**.